# vs2005 c# .net 2.0: Short cuts templates for VS2005

Tags: c#, .net

I really like the following template to create properties for class in VS2005

```
Type Prop<tab><tab>
```

and it gives template for writing class property.

What are some of the other ones.. Is there a place where I can get list of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theyre actually called snippets and you can create your own. in VS (at least 2008) you can rightclick and do Insert Snippet (or Surround With) to see a list of whats currently available.

Also you can see them under Tools > Code Snippets Manager.

[Snippy](http://www.codeplex.com/snippy) is also a nice little editor for making your own.